# Memory Error After reducing datatype of array

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a rather large dataset X containing 60660 vectors each with 36 features. I cannot share the data since it is confidential, but np.random.rand(60660, 36) will create a random matrix of the same shape with float64 values from 0 to 1 which is very similar to my matrix. I am trying to calculate the Euclidian distance of this matrix, but I get the following memory error

Example Code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances

X = np.random.rand(60660, 36)
distances = euclidean_distances(X, squared=True)


MemoryError: Unable to allocate 27.4 GiB for an array with shape (60660, 60660) and data type float64
```

This makes sense because I am essentially calculating a 60660 x 60660 array with float64 values which will certainly cause me to run out of ram. What I do not understand is if I reduce the datatype of the array to float16 for example I still get the same memory error.

Example Code:

```
X = np.random.rand(60660, 36).astype('float16')
distances = euclidean_distances(X, squared=True)

MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [18], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 X = np.random.rand(60660, 36).astype('float16')
----> 2 distances = euclidean_distances(X, squared=True)

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\gm_work\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py:328, in euclidean_distances(X, Y, Y_norm_squared, squared, X_norm_squared)
    322     if Y_norm_squared.shape != (1, Y.shape[0]):
    323         raise ValueError(
    324             f"Incompatible dimensions for Y of shape {Y.shape} and "
    325             f"Y_norm_squared of shape {original_shape}."
    326         )
--> 328 return _euclidean_distances(X, Y, X_norm_squared, Y_norm_squared, squared)

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\gm_work\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py:369, in _euclidean_distances(X, Y, X_norm_squared, Y_norm_squared, squared)
    366     distances = _euclidean_distances_upcast(X, XX, Y, YY)
    367 else:
    368     # if dtype is already float64, no need to chunk and upcast
--> 369     distances = -2 * safe_sparse_dot(X, Y.T, dense_output=True)
    370     distances += XX
    371     distances += YY

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 27.4 GiB for an array with shape (60660, 60660) and data type float64
​
```

Why do I still get the same error noting the data type is still float64 even though I am casting X as float16?

I tried running this with a smaller input array (10000 x 36) with float16 datatype and it works just fine, but the output array is still float64, so is it not possible to reduce the datatype? Any suggestions on how I can get this to work with my original array?

Comment: Test this with a smaller case and check the dtype of the result.  And if possible,look at the code for `euclidean_distances`.  Not all `numpy` calculations retain the dtype of the inputs.

Comment: The reason for the same messages is that the array is generated the same way each time, before being reduced to `float16` in the second case. Do you need to have float numbers? If not, you can try out the [np.random.randint()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) function

Comment: Show the full traceback.  That may tell us/you what part of the calculation is producing the large full array.

Comment: @ChrisSc, I do have to use float since the original array is a MinMax scaled time series array where each column is a different sensor measurement.

Comment: Thanks @MikeJadwin. My only suggestions are: to process the array in chunks, or perform preprocessing at the data source. Both of these are intended to reduce the amount of memory you would need at one time. These will most likely complicate the code & processing somewhat